# Pyparsing setParseAction method in python 2.7 throws exceptions

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, pyparsing

This is a general problem with `pyparsing` and python 2.7 (in 3 it works just fine). The general structure is this:

```
class SomeParser(object):

    def some_action(self, string, loc, tok):
         print("action")

    def gramma(self):
          ...pyparsing gramma for some 

             language....
         some_rule = (token + token2).setParseAction(self.some_action)
         return some_rule

     def parse(self, string):
         self.gramma().parseString(string)
         return True
```

In python3 `pyparsing` works just fine, in 2.7 however I get

```
Parsing error : some_action() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)
```

My question is how to make it work in both versions?

EDIT: After some test I found that it is general problem, not only with class methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a problem (with a help of a friend), which is in `pyparsing` 1.5.6 and its `_trim_arity` function that tries to guess the number of arguments that func in `setParseAction(func)` is accepting. I changed it from:

```
if not _PY3K:                                                                                                                                                               
    def _trim_arity(func, maxargs=2):                                                                                                                                                 
        limit = [0]                                                                                                                                                                   
        def wrapper(*args):                                                                                                                                                           
            while 1:                                                                                                                                                                  
                try:                                                                                                                                                                  
                    return func(*args[limit[0]:])                                                                                                                                     
                except TypeError:                                                                                                                                                     
                    if limit[0] <= maxargs:                                                                                                                                           
                        limit[0] += 1                                                                                                                                                 
                        continue                                                                                                                                                      
                    raise                                                                                                                                                             
        return wrapper                                                                                                                                                                
    else:                                                                                                                                                                                 
        def _trim_arity(func, maxargs=2):                                                                                                                                                 
            limit = maxargs                                                                                                                                                             
            def wrapper(*args):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                #~ nonlocal limit                                                                                                                                                         
                while 1:                                                                                                                                                                  
                    try:                                                                                                                                                                  
                        return func(*args[limit:])                                                                                                                                        
                    except TypeError:                                                                                                                                                     
                        if limit:                                                                                                                                                         
                            limit -= 1                                                                                                                                                    
                            continue                                                                                                                                                      
                        raise                                                                                                                                                             
            return wrapper
```

to:

```
if not _PY3K and False:                                                                                                                                                               
    def _trim_arity(func, maxargs=2):                                                                                                                                                 
        limit = [0]                                                                                                                                                                   
        def wrapper(*args):                                                                                                                                                           
            while 1:                                                                                                                                                                  
                try:                                                                                                                                                                  
                    return func(*args[limit[0]:])                                                                                                                                     
                except TypeError:                                                                                                                                                     
                    if limit[0] <= maxargs:                                                                                                                                           
                        limit[0] += 1                                                                                                                                                 
                        continue                                                                                                                                                      
                    raise                                                                                                                                                             
        return wrapper                                                                                                                                                                
    else:                                                                                                                                                                                 
        def _trim_arity(func, maxargs=2):                                                                                                                                                 
            # limit = maxargs                                                                                                                                                             
            def wrapper(*args):                                                                                                                                                           
                limit = maxargs                                                                                                                                                           
                #~ nonlocal limit                                                                                                                                                         
                while 1:                                                                                                                                                                  
                    try:                                                                                                                                                                  
                        return func(*args[limit:])                                                                                                                                        
                    except TypeError:                                                                                                                                                     
                        if limit:                                                                                                                                                         
                            limit -= 1                                                                                                                                                    
                            continue                                                                                                                                                      
                        raise                                                                                                                                                             
            return wrapper
```

Not very elegant but I can see that in the `trunk` version on pyparsing it is fixed already.

Comment: Yes, I've found that the `_trim_arity` function causes many irritating errors in pyparsing.

Comment: @BrenBarn fortunatelly in the trunk this is fixed and I think optimized a bit, waiting for realase, in a meantime this is a good workaround.